# computing the Taylor series for $e^{1-\cos x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I was told to compute the Taylor series for $e^{1-\cos x}$ to the fourth degree.
I plugged the Taylor series for $1-\cos x$ into the Taylor series for $e$.
This got me: $$1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{(\frac{-x^2}2)^2}{2}$$A bit of simplification results in: $1+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}6$.
Is this correct? The answer key to the question gave a different answer - it put the denominator of the last term as 12 instead of 6. However, I do not see the flaw in my calculations. Did I make the error or did they?

Comment: You made an error.

Comment: where did I err?

Comment: You will need terms of $1-\cos x$ up to the $x^4$ term.

Comment: Your signs on $\dfrac{x^2}2$ are inconsistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer agrees with the answer key:

$\cos x=1-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^4}{24}+O(x^6),$ so $1-\cos x=\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{x^4}{24}+O(x^6),$

so $\exp(1-\cos x)=1 + \left(\dfrac{x^2}2 - \dfrac{x^4}{24} \right)+ \dfrac12\left(\dfrac{x^2}2\right)^2+O(x^6)=1 + \dfrac{x^2}2 + \dfrac{x^4}{12}+O(x^6).$

Comment: No - you are right. The answer key had 12. not 8. I corrected it in the question.

Comment: Well then I agree with the answer key

Comment: can you explain what the o is in front of the $x^6$?

Comment: It should be $o(x^4)$ or $O(x^6)$.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks, @egreg; I corrected accordingly

Comment: @burt:  see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) about big (and little) O notation

Answer (score 2):

For a check, it's not really difficult to compute the derivatives:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=e^{1-\cos x} & f(0)&=1 \\
f'(x)&=e^{1-\cos x}\sin x & f'(0)&=0 \\
f''(x)&=e^{1-\cos x}(\sin^2x+\cos x) & f''(0)&=1 \\
f'''(x)&=e^{1-\cos x}(\sin^3x+3\sin x\cos x-\sin x) & f'''(0)&=0 \\
f''''(x)&=e^{1-\cos x}(\sin^4x+3\sin^2x\cos x-\sin x\cos x+3\cos^2x-\cos x) & f''''(0)&=2
\end{align}
Thus
$$
e^{1-\cos x}=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{12}+o(x^4)
$$